# Can real analysis help in understanding calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have been trying to understand calculus but couldnt.In a few answers, it was written that calculus and real analysis are closely related.So can learning real analysis help in understanding calculus? Is it enough if I learn certain parts of real analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is the other way. It is calculus that is very intuitive and gives you a lot of results immediately, whereas real analysis goes to the foundations and justifies the steps we take in calculus.  For example the chain rule for differentiation and integration by parts are simply stated in Calculus. These are proved rigorously by analysis.

Real analysis warns us when certain things we routinely assume may not be valid, for example differentiating an infinite series of functions term by term.  It constructs a function that is continuous but not differentiable at all.

Comment: Yes.Thats what I am looking for.Derivations for the results used in calculus,Clear explanation of applying limits(I think this is the basis for calculus),etc..

Comment: @Mohan I should warn you though, if your motivation for studying analysis is to understand calculus; i.e. if you don't get calculus but want to learn analysis to do so, you might not get very far. In part this is because every Analysis book I know of (Abbott and Rudin, among others) assumes robust introductory calculus knowledge. Calculus gives you the intuition considered by many to be necessary to learn the formal background of Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to simply recommend that you get a copy of *Calculus*, by Michael Spivak. It does a lovely job of introducing calculus rigorously, while sticking to the Riemann integral (you'll learn about Lebesgue integration in a decent analysis course). It's not an easy book by any means, but everyone I know who ever used it still has their copy and opens it often (and that includes several working mathematicians).

It also has the charm that it starts with the basics -- a bunch of axioms for the real numbers, and some proofs about them, to get you used to the idea of proving things, and to see (by beautiful examples) how proofs are written.

Some folks will say that this is really an analysis book. So be it. Whatever you want to call it, it's a superb introduction to some very important mathematics that happens to include most of the stuff taught in most calculus courses (and a good deal more).

Comment: Thank you.I tried learning the book.In this text, while introducing integrals the author explained a lot about partitioning the area under the curve and defined the integral.The way I understood this is, as we increase the number of divisions in the partition the lower sum and upper sum approach the same value and this value is the area under the curve.Am I understanding it right? Please explain.

Comment: That is, broadly speaking, the main idea of Riemann integration. But there are lots of details. (i) just increasing the *number* of divisions isn't enough -- you have to also ensure the size of the smallest interval in the partitions goes to zero, (ii) the lower and upper sums may not approach the same value (iii) others I'm surely forgetting. That's why the definition is so precise, and uses the set of *all* partitions, and the greatest lower bound and least upper bound of the associated sets of upper and lower sums, etc. I can't explain it in a comment -- Spivak wrote a whole book to do so!

Answer (score 1):

"Calculus" 2nd Edition, volumes 1 and 2, 1966 by Tom M. Apostol was recommended to me as a jewel.  I love both volumes.  It is loaded with problems, where most of my learning occurred, and is also spiced with proofs.

Actually, math students of different backgrounds will prefer different books.  I studied calculus in high school, but not in college.  Then 35 years later I decided to attack it for a hobby.

Whatever book you choose: here are some generic tips:
1. Heavily research the reviews (e.g. Amazon user comments)
2. Choose one with a **lot** of problems.
 
3. Don't be in a hurry.
4. Don't skip any problems.  For the problems you can't solve, post the problem (heavily showing your work) on a math forum, like this site.

Comment: how is this relevant to the question?

Comment: @JobHunter69 Depends on *which* question that you are referring to.  I inferred that the OP's (i.e. original poster's) *underlying issue* was captured by "I have been trying to understand calculus but couldnt."  My response expresses my opinion of the best way for someone to learn calculus, which is by finding the right book for them.